# Connecting two instance of Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I have two instance of Hyperledger Fabric install and running of different machines(one in on ubuntu and other one is on windows). Now i want that these two share their public ledger together.

What changes i have to make on both machines for the same and where?

Comment: Where do you run ordering service?

Comment: And what do you mean by instances?

Comment: @ArtemBarger currently I am running ordering service on both machines.

Comment: @GariSingh by instance means i am running a full Hyperledger Fabric on each machine.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the thing, let's start from terms and definitions, specifying the Hyperledger Fabric network entities.

1. Network peer - used to maintain chaincodes (smart contracts), keeps replicated copy of the the ledger and most recent status update.
2. Ordering service/ Consensus - key objective of it is to specify total order on incoming transactions and cut the block, which will be distributed among all peers.

The flow works as following:

1. Client submits transaction proposal to endorsing peers.
2. Endorsing peers simulates transaction by means of invoking chaincode and signing on the results.
3. Signed chaincode response sent back to the client.
4. Client collects all responses and send result to the ordering service
5. Ordering service cut the block with transaction according to certain criteria - number of transactions or block size
6. Block distributed to the peers for validation
7. Once validate block being committed to the local ledger of the peer and state is updated accordingly

Back to your case, I'd assume two instances simply means that you have two different organizations. So what you need to do is to:

1. Define/decide where you would like to run ordering service which will take care of transactions order.
2. Define a channel with two organizations
3. In `configtx.yaml` you need to specify the address of the ordering service.
4. Create a channel to generate genesis block
5. Join all peers for both organization using the genesis block

Now since ordering service endpoint is endcoded in configuration transaction each organization will elect one peer to open connection to the ordering service to pull new blocks. Finally this leader will distribute blocks inside its own organization.

Just to summarize, to make two "instance" (here I assume independent set of peers) connected you need to make them connected to same channel moreover you need to make sure they will be connected to same ordering service.

Comment: The above scenario assumes a priori knowledge of a static members set. How can a community evolve? If I start with a CA, an Ordering Service and an Endorsing Peer, how can I dynamically add organizations to a channel or add more channels? Also, how can I add more peers to an organization after the initial deployment. I see there is a Membership Service Provider, but it is not clear if it address the requirement of a adding Peers, Channels and Ordering Services post initial deployment.

Comment: Actually nothing here assumes a priori knowledge, you can leverage config update transactions to add new organization. At any given point in time you can generate a new crypto material for peer and use root ca of org to sign on certificate then you can join peer to existing channel. Currently Hyperledger Fabric supports dynamicity and allowing ad hoc addition of new orgs and peers.

Comment: @ArtemBarger as peers are running on different machines will peer channel join -b <channel_ID.block> sufficient to join the channel? or will ordering service will take care of this?

Comment: peer channel join -b <channel_ID.block>  will me sufficient, as block has information how to get connected to the ordering service.

Comment: @ArtemBarger it will be great if you can share some demo link for Hyperledger Fabric dynamicity and allowing ad hoc addition of new orgs and peers. As i have already tried passing the genesis block id created on my ubuntu machine(i am able to add new peers and orgs on this machine easily) to join a peer running on windows machine but i am not successful in the same.

Comment: please take a look here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/master/examples/configtxupdate/README.md